# Android Studio - App freeze instead of crash

Tags: android, macos, android-studio, crash

I have a weird question. My application never crashes.. it freeze my phone instead. Even when i throw exception it freeze with no error log.

Its for sure not device problem (tried on 3 devices) and not application problem (tried on few test projects). For sure its Android Studio problem, because it works properly on Eclipse environment.

I'm using Android Studio 1.2.2 and Mac OSX.

*EDIT: same issue reported by several other users, with no other specific information given. App freezes, and log only shows "Android VM shutting down". Crashlytics not present, however Google Analytics is present, with ga_reportUncaughtExceptions=false*

## Solution

In comments below Saket reported:

> This was happening at my side because I had registered a wrongly configured UncaughtExceptionHandler by calling Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()

So just find all `uncaughtExceptionHandler` strings in your project and try to comment/remove them.

Comment: Probably not Android Studio. You probably have something doing so much work on your main thread that it's just 'freezing' while its doing the work

Comment: I'm sure that it isn't application problem - I created 'Hello World' application and throw UnsupportedOperationException on click... it do the same

Comment: I have the same problem on Windows... most probably Android Studio or Gradle

Comment: I use Android Studio 1.3.3 preview with gradle android plugin 1.3.0-beta3. also tried gradle android plugin 1.2.3

Comment: Thats actually happening with latest Android Studio and gradle pluggin. It made debugging really painful in finding crashes. But fortunately running apk on simulator crashes the app immediately and displayed the crash logs

Comment: Or this can be latest google play services issue. In Analytics recording crashes and interfering with default crash handling

Comment: This was happening at my side because I had registered a wrongly configured `UncaughtExceptionHandler` by calling `Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()`

Comment: Also wanted to write the same. Can't understant why that question is closed? There's a right answer in a comment above!

Comment: How was the `UncaughtExceptionHandler` wrongly configured?

Comment: OK. In your uncaught exception handler, you need to call the original exception handler (the result of `Thread.getDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler()`).